# Match Against Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price
FROM products AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON p.account_id = a.account_id
MATCH(p.title) AGAINST('+images')
```

I'm trying to use a MATCH for the first time. It says that I have a syntax error and I am not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `WHERE` keyword before conditions that aren't part of the join:

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price
FROM products AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON p.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE MATCH(p.title) AGAINST('+images')
```

Comment: Just curious, can this be a join condition? `JOIN stuff ON stuff AND MATCH(stuff) AGAINST (stuff)`? Or can MATCH only be used in the where clause?

Comment: `MATCH` can be used in any expression. But in this case, he's not using it as part of a join, so the proper place is the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @McAdam331 Does it give a syntax error (you don't need the tables to test!)

Comment: @Strawberry of course, but this was a faster answer. I will admit that I was lazy there. Also, Barmar, thanks for the input. I know it shouldn't be used here, but I was curious if it could be.

Comment: @McAdam331 The only functions that have restrictions on where they can be used are aggregate functions.